# Is there a way to crack the windows Administrator password in Linux (using the SAM file) WITHOUT resetting it?

Tags: windows, linux, security, passwords

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to crack the windows Administrator password in Linux (using the SAM file) WITHOUT resetting it?](https://superuser.com/questions/237935/is-there-a-way-to-crack-the-windows-administrator-password-in-linux-using-the-sa)

Ok so Ive already got Ubuntu 10.10 on a usb bootstick. Chntpw is installed as well. What I'm wondering is are there any programs to crack as in decrypt the SAM file and show the password but not erase it? Most Linux programs Ive come across don't do this. They just reset the password.

I have tried Ophrack

Comment: This isn't a programming question, and doesn't belong here.

Comment: yes it is. i didnt know that stack overflow could migrate posts so I posted on superuser as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ophcrack](http://ophcrack.sourceforge.net/) can (potentially) crack (recover) the password from the SAM file by using rainbow tables.

Comment: Ive tried Ophrack

Comment: With what result? You need to provide more details for us to be able to help you.

Comment: I'd assume he's only using the free tables that are limited to LM <=14 char alphanumerics.  He's going to have to brute it or rainbow it.  I'd try to get my hands on additional tables if I were him...